# Forecasting temperature using CurveFitting

Tags: regression, matlab, curve-fitting

I am assigned with a academic task to forecast temperature using CurveFitting.

Please suggest me whether I use Linear regression/ Non-Linear regression or extrapolation? I have to forecast 1 next week (days from 16 to 23) temperature.

```
 days=[1:15];

temp=[34    36    38    35    36    37    40    41    39    40    41    38  39    42    40];
```

I have searched over the internet but couldn't found solution for it so I thought someone could be possibly helping me out here.

I am a beginner so please keep patience with blunders. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment probably is only to manifest your skills using that kinds of regression. So, try applying both and compare results as for the significance of terms (t-statistics of coefficients), adjusted R squared or Bayesian Information Criterion.
However, practically, time series methods would be more appropriate.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated image and tell me I am going good with extrapolation.

Comment: The linear is fine. The other apparently is quadratic curve, which is practically unfeasible for such a long forecast period, unless there is a prior information on such behaviour or theoretical grounds for it.